# Array containing unknown number of variables.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am working on a proof, and I have a variable I want to define as an array containing an a constant plus an unknown (or infinite) number of variables. What is the correct notation to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say your rows are indexed by some set $I$ and the columns by $J$. I would typically write $$[a_{i,j}]_{i \in I, j \in J}$$
or, when $I$ and $J$ are clear from context, just $[a_{i,j}]$.

This probably lines up with matrices you're more used to. In the case of an $(m \times n)$ matrix we have $I=\{1, \dots, m\}$ and $J = \{1, \dots, n\}$. The matrix with values indexed by these sets are notated
$$
[a_{i,j}]_{i \in I, j \in J}\text{.}
$$

(I use square brackets throughout because I personally denote matrices with square brackets. This is my own taste; others have used round brackets. Also, I've seen many people omit the subscript commas and just write $[a_{ij}]$. Do whatever you think is clearest for your audience.)

Comment: Are both i and j necessary does [ai]i∈I work?

Comment: It depends on what you're denoting. The notation $[a_i]_{i \in I}$ just suggests a family of objects $a_i$ indexed by one set $I$. Examples include row and column vectors, which could be denoted $[a_i]_{1 \leq i \leq n}$. Your use of the word "array" suggested to me that the indexing would be "2-dimensional" like the indexing of positions in a matrix.

Comment: If you're determined to only have one thing in the subscript then you could group together the two subscripts $i$ and $j$ into a single tuple $(i,j)$ and write $[a_{(i,j)}]_{(i,j) \in I \times J}$, but that's a (very contrived) cosmetic change, as I'm sure you'll agree